# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation not only rotate, but also move and stretch UIImageView

Tags: iphone, transform

I'm trying to rotate `UIImageView` for certain degrees with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()` function, but it end with image not only rotates, but also moved to another coordinates and stretched o.O I have no clue why do this happen... Here is a code:

`self.arrowToPoi.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI / 4 )`

Don't know if this can help, but `UIImageView` resides inside custom `UITableCellView`, which automatically changes its' height to accommodate `WebView` content.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with auto-resize and auto-position feature of `UIImageView` and height changing after `WebView` content loaded. To solved the problem by fixing outer left and outer top arrows.

Comment: I'm glad I found this answer.  In moving from iOS 5.1 to iOS 6 and supporting the iPhone 5, my rotated UIImageViews were either badly skewed (UIViewContentModeScaleToFill) or wrongly-sized (UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill).  This helped me resolve the issue.

Comment: what are outer left and outer top arrows anyway? can you be more specific?

Answer (score 4):

1. Try selecting the appropriate `contentMode` (property how the image is adjusted when the `bounds` change, what they do). Default is `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`, with for example `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` there is strange behavior which sounds similar to your problem.
2. Be aware that it's rotated around the `UIImageView`'s center.

Answer (score 2):

I have a UIImageView in a UITableViewCell object that requires rotation.  I also was experiencing a skew along with my rotation.  It was solved by setting the view mode of my UIImageView to `Center`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are using Autolayout (new feature comming with iOS 6.x). If so, disable it.

I experienced exactly the same problem. Disabling Autolayout worked for me. You can disable it, by selecting the Storyboard file in Xcode and then selecting the File inspector and there unchecking the checkbox "Use Autolayout".

Hope this helps anybody that comes along...